# Que signifie le mot « conventionnel » dans ce passage?

Tags: sens, expressions

Que signifie le mot « conventionnel » dans ce passage :

> « L’objectif reste marqué par une volonté de distance critique par rapport au patrimoine. Seuls le rapport constant à l’histoire, aux exigences de ses méthodes, la prudence de ses hypothèses susceptibles de dégager une recherche ardente sur le patrimoine ancien, empêcherait le retour du passé comme une image mythique, idéaliste et inlassablement reprise qui risquerait sans cette distance critique de rester purement ***conventionnel***. » ?

Comment: D'où provient cet extrait qui ne semble pas être publié ? Il faut lire et relire la phrase plusieurs fois pour tenter de comprendre à quoi *conventionnel* s'applique... (*passé conventionnel* ?)

Comment: C'est une thèse de doctorat non publiée

Comment: Peux-tu stp vérifier l'orthographe de _seuls_, _empêcherait_ et _conventionnel_ ?

Comment: Bonjour suiiurisesse. J'ai copié collé le texte tel quel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce texte est "jargonnant", obscur sans être poétique. Ce que je comprends: le retour du passé risque de rester purement conventionnel et formel sans une méthode historique rigoureuse. Ces méthodes devraient permettre d'éviter de colporter toujours les mêmes images mythiques sur le passé : pour être un peu familier, si quelqu'un vous dit "c'était mieux avant", on peut lui conseiller de lire l'histoire du "[court XXᵉ siècle 1914-1991](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C3%82ge_des_extr%C3%AAmes)" selon la formule de l'historien britannique Eric Hobsbawm.

Comment: Merci énormément